# How to get real part of number?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I am using `roots` on a polynomial and i need to compare the roots with 0.When i am using roots the code breaks with `invalid comparison method`.I have looked into cmath library but there is no `real(myvariable)` method

```
def compute(self):
    rts=roots(self.b)
    zs=0
    zd=0
    for val in rts:
        if val>0:
            zd=zd+1
        else:
            zs=zs+1
```

Comment: It's not a *function*, it's a *field* or *attribute* to the object.  Try `a = 5 + 3j`, `print(a.real)`.

Comment: val does not have a property called "real" .The auto complete does not see it.

Comment: What is `roots`?  How can I get it?  And what is `self.b` ?

Comment: I am using roots from sympy library

Comment: How about `sympy.real_roots()`?

Comment: You should mention your context in the question, providing a [mcve].  In this case I was mislead to believe you are using maybe `numpy.roots()`.

Comment: Well i added the sympy tag i am sorry.

Comment: PS. I need the real part of each of the roots. If i have root=2+3j  i need 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `re(z)` is how you take the real part of a complex number in SymPy. But there are other issues here.

1. `roots` returns a dictionary in which the values encode multiplicities. Your code ignores multiplicities, simply adding 1. Better to either use those values, or maybe use `multiple=True` flag of `roots` which makes it return a list instead, with multiple roots repeated.
2. `roots` will only return the roots that are expressible in radicals. For polynomials of degrees up to 4 these are all of them, but for higher degrees you will likely be missing some or all of roots. The `rootof` function is suitable for these cases: it takes the index of a root as a second argument.

Accordingly, I give two examples. First, using `roots` with `multiple` flag, so it returns a list instead of a dict:

```
z = symbols('z')
p = Poly([3, 4, 5, 2], z)
rts = roots(p, multiple=True)
print([re(val) for val in rts])
```

These values can be compared to 0.

Second, a higher degree polynomial: we don't expect roots in radicals anymore.

```
z = symbols('z')
p = Poly([3, 4, 5, 2, 7, 5, 9], z)
for k in range(degree(p)):
    print(re(rootof(p, k).n()))
```

Output:

```
-1.05474041145861
-1.05474041145861
-0.364466197630592
-0.364466197630592
0.752539942422535
0.752539942422535
```

which makes sense because the complex roots of a polynomial with real coefficients come in conjugate pairs.

Comment: In that context i do not need symbols anymore.It can be a straight numeric array of coefficients and i want to compare the roots with 0. I used sympy for roots because i found the method in that library and assumed that is the right method.

Comment: Okay, then the second code sample is what you want.

Comment: In what library is rootof?

Comment: Same as roots, [see the docs](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/polys/reference.html#sympy.polys.rootoftools.rootof)